# How to install the voice component on F1 2018

Tags: steam, pc, f1-2018

When I first started playing F1 2018 (Steam - PC) I did not like the idea of having the voice command software installed (or see the need for it), so when the game was installing I skipped the installation for that bit of software.

Now, however, I'm at the point where I want to be communicating with the team, but finding it really difficult to select the option from the L1 menu (using xbox controller). I need to have a really long straight so I can select the correct option, as it's too difficult when also steering. This can be problematic on circuits without many long straights.

Does anyone know how I can now get this installed and setup?
(Without reinstalling preferably)

I tried verifying the cache but it doesn't seem to trigger the installation.

Comment: When installed through Steam, (stand-alone) auxiliary software (like Visual Basic runtime and DirectX) can usually be found inside the game's installation folder. Have you checked to see if the voice control component is present there?

Comment: @Joachim I'll have a look when I'm at home and report back!